# Do out-of-view objects on Canvas consume memory?

Tags: javascript, canvas

If I'm continuously drawing objects on canvas, and moving the old objects out of boundary,  does the old object still consume memory?

For example this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccLze/)

```
var canvas = d3.select("body").append("canvas")
                .attr("width", 200)
                .attr("height", 200);
var ctx = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "#f00";

(function tick() {
    ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 10, 10);
    ctx.translate(10, 10);
    setTimeout(tick, 500);
})();
```

I'm continuously drawing rects, while moving the old rects out of site.

**Observation**

Suggested by @meagar, I tried Chrome profiler, it seems the out-of-view objects don't consume memory.

Comment: Trivially easy to test in Chrome's developer tools. Run your program, watch the memory graph.

Comment: @meagar Nice.  Never think of that.  I will try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes and No.**

Yes, the CPU will process the javascript which draws your rectangles.

No, the GPU will not attempt to draw rectangles that are **totally** off the canvas.

Comment: The canvas itself should take a fairly fixed amount of memory. The JavaScript objects to represent the things that should be drawn may take more.

Comment: According to the `yes` part, If I draw rects continuously, the memory consumption will increase accordingly?  Am I understanding it right?

Comment: @tadman. Yep! The objects representing the rectangles will take up memory whether they are drawn or not.  If those rectangles might move in and out of the canvas you must keep all those rectangles in memory.  If a rectangle goes off-canvas and never returns, then you can conserve memory by "recycling" that object when a new object is required.

Comment: @gongzhitaao Drawing additional rectangles using fillRect will not increase your memory used.  That's because canvas draws your new rectangle and immediately "forgets" everything about that rectangle (no memory required since everything is forgotten).  But if you create objects which "remember" info about the rectangle then you will consume more memory as you add more rectangles.  A common design pattern to avoid this extra memory usage is to "recycle" objects that will never return to the canvas (replace off-canvas object info with your new rect info).  Good luck with your project!

Comment: @markE *immediately "forgets" everything*! That's it :D Thanks.